# Design a drawing api for Canvas

Tags: haskell, threepenny-gui

I am adding some function to threepenny ui api.
I would like to had the ability to draw line with canvas.

The function that I can write have the following signature:

```
moveTo :: Vector -> UI ()
lineTo :: Vector -> UI ()
stroke :: UI ()
strokeStyle :: UI ()
beginPath :: UI ()
```

Each primitive `moveTo` and `lineTo` should happen in between a `beginPath` .. stroke call.
How would you enforce the `beginPath` ...  stroke sequence. By design I would like to give the user no choice for drawing lines. So the user is not aware of the `beginPath` ... stroke sequence.

Comment: I suggest going with a functional, semantically meaningful API, like [graphics-drawingcombinators](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/graphics-drawingcombinators), instead of this imperative-style one.  The point is, the values you are building are images, not series' of commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would design a canvas API.

```
newtype Drawing = ...
instance Monoid Drawing where ... -- for combining drawings

line :: Vector -> Vector -> Drawing
path :: [Vector] -> Drawing
withStyle :: Style -> Drawing -> Drawing
runDrawing :: Drawing -> UI ()
```

Here the functions operate on semantically meaningful objects (from the user's perspective), rather than imperative commands.  This should be implementable with the type

```
newtype Drawing = Drawing (UI ())
```

however sometimes subtleties will require that the type have a bit more structure, so be open to that (e.g. `Something -> UI ()`).

Answer (score 2):

It's definitely good to design your API so that it can't be used improperly. One approach you might take here is to create an un-exported wrapper that lets you control how these particular actions are composed (I haven't tried to run this, sorry):

```
-- Don't export constructor
newtype Line a = Line { runLine :: UI a }

-- Wrap the return types in your current implementation with Line, for:
moveTo :: Vector -> Line ()
lineTo :: Vector -> Line ()
...

instance Monad Line where
         (Line ui) >>= f = Line (ui >>= \a-> beginPath >> (runLine $ f a))
         return = Line . return
```

A couple other points:

1. You may want to use a `Monoid` instance instead, if your API doesn't need to bind any values (i.e. all of your line API functions end in `-> Line ()`
2. If you need to do something like wrap the entire sequence of composed line actions in e.g. `start` and `end` actions or whatever, you could further extend the above with

   ```
   runLine (Line ui) = start >> ui >> end
   ```